# Why isn't right piston moving down even if a heavy car is resting on it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

I have understood the concept that pressure at same height should be equal but what about the weight of car that will also push the piston and pressure would change and left piston should go up, some budy explain me the application of Pascal's law to the hydraulic lift.

Answer (score 0):

Yes someone should apply some force to balance the pressure force on the left piston. However the pressure force on the right piston is balanced by the weight of car. But the pressure force on the right piston is much larger than left piston. Because pressure force = pressure*area. Area of right piston is much larger than left piston. Excess pressure is same everywhere inside the liquid.

Comment: So how could we use this system to lift car from right piston by applying force from left piston, u just said that we have to balance it from left piston then how could i apply some force from left and lift the car from right?

Comment: push the left piston so that right piston will move up. Your applied force is small compared to the pressure force on right piston .